# How can I track and test a modem's network connectivity in iOS? I need to log parameters from the modem and network which might be secure by Apple

Tags: ios, iphone, networking, modem

My work wants to test their new modems using an iPhone app. We can use a current app or build a brand new one. Third party apps are OK but want to avoid jailbreaking if possible.

We want an app which connects to the network and monitors certain parameters for a set amount of time. We will log attributes from the network and modem. We already know it's possible to test speed, disconnections, reconnection time etc. Some of the parameters we need to track might be more secure or outside Apple's regulations.

These are the responses we are looking for:

Frequency (ie. 2462MHz)

Channel Bandwidth (ie. 20MHz, 40MHz)

Radio Type (ie. 802.11a,b,g,n,ac)

802.11 Deauth Reason code

802.11 Association Status code

How can we track the above attributes using an iOS app? 
Are there any apps out there that can track this information? Does iOS have anything for tracking these parameters?

Thanks so much!!

Comment: How are you connecting? Via network and SNMP?

Comment: either or will suffice.